# replegar menú cuando doy click en cualquier parte fuera de él

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sucede que tengo mi página web la cual va bien. Tengo un mené estilo hamburguesa el cual se despliega cuando uno pulsa sobre el respectivo boton de menu. Para ello lo logré con este código:

```
 $('#icono-menu').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (contador == 0) {
                    $('#menu').removeClass('mostrarmenu');

                    contador = 1;
                } else {
                    $('#menu').addClass('mostrarmenu');
                    contador = 0;



                }
            });
```

No obstante cuando el menú se despliega para volverlo a replegar solo tengo que pulsar en el boton hamburguesa. Lo que quiero es que el menu se repliegue siempre y cuando se le pulse en cualquier parte de la página yno solo en el botón.

Por ejemplo aquí: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar haciendo un event listener global, algo asi como:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).click(
    function(){
      $("#menu").removeClass("mostrarmenu");
    }
  );
});
```

No lo he probado, pero en una libreria que uso cuando mando a llamar removeClass, si la clase no existe no hace nada, si la clase existe la remueve